# Returning html tag names in array that match a tag name query

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to return all HTML tags given a tag query, push ONLY the tag names of returned tags and print them to the console. However, I'm being returned an array of the tag names, but all of the html lines too.

For example, given the following HTML markup:

```
<div></div>
<div id="backgroundred" class="blackfont center>
```

I want to be able to return an array of `[div, div]`, but am instead of being returned with `[div, div#backgroundred.blackfont.center]`. With my JS code below, how can I return just the tag names in the array?

```
let tagQuery = "div";
let sss = [];
let tagMatch = document.getElementsByTagName(CSS.escape(tag));
sss.push(tagMatch);
console.log(sss);
```

I know `querySelector` can achieve this, but I'm curious about using other methods to do this. So please, no answers with `querySelector`

Comment: "I know querySelector can achieve this" — No, it can't. Both it and `getElementsByTagName` select **elements**, not strings representing the tag names of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array.from` instead, and pass a second parameter to map each element to just its tag name:

```js
const tagNames = Array.from(
  document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
  element => element.tagName.toLowerCase()
);
console.log(tagNames);
```

```html
<div></div>
<div id="backgroundred" class="blackfont center"></div>
```

Still, it's kind of odd to extract the tag names when you *already know* that you're selecting `div` tags, you could just check the length of the collection instead and `.fill` an array, if you wanted

```js
const tagName = 'div';
const tagNames = new Array(document.getElementsByTagName(tagName).length).fill(tagName);
console.log(tagNames);
```

```html
<div></div>
<div id="backgroundred" class="blackfont center"></div>
```

Comment: An alternative would be `Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div"), element => element.tagName.toLowerCase())`.